# How do I import other Swift files into a Swift script?

Tags: swift, import

I am writing a Swift script and I want to keep it clean. The way I would do this is by create multiple files and importing them. However, I can't figure out how to import another file into a Swift script. I am ***not*** using Xcode.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There's currently no way to import other swift files in a *interpreted* swift script. But you can concatenate all source files before executing them:

```
cat one.swift two.swift three.swift | swift -
```

---

If you're using the swift compiler, just add the files you want to compile together before the `-o` argument:

```
swiftc one.swift two.swift three.swift -o combined
```

No need to import them, they are already in the same module.

Comment: Piping did not work for me, but concatenating into file and then running it (same bash script) seems possible.

Comment: I'm trying to get a console app working (no XCode). The `swiftc` with all of my files that have classes worked. I had to rename my main driver file to `main.swift` to have top level functions.